# Drupal Leaflet View loading view block through Ajax

Tags: views, 8, ajax

I created a view block for displaying geocodeed nodes on a View Leaflet map.
Everything working, the map displays the markers as I want.
Now, I would like to load this map throught drupal ajax

I attached the leaflet libraries to the page.
Then I load the view with:

```
$view = Views::getView('map');

$view->setArguments($args);
$view->setDisplay('block');
$view->preExecute();
$view->execute();
$content = $this->renderer->render($view->render());

$response->addCommand(
    new HtmlCommand('.result__map', $content)
 ));
```

The $content contain only an empty div generatated from the view and when the response is instered in the Dom nothing happen.
I suspesct that the map is missing some JS trigger to instanciante the map and maybe some JS settings.

Could someone send me an example or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the [ViewExecutable::buildRenderable](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21ViewExecutable.php/function/ViewExecutable%3A%3AbuildRenderable/8.2.x) function.

Instead of:

```
$content = $this->renderer->render($view->render());
```

You must do like this:

```
$content = $view->buildRenderable('block', $args);
```

Comment: hi @Jdrupal  Thank you for your answer .. now the map is lading the Json object is sent but the Key  `"feature:[]" ` is empty.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question. Is the view not being sent with ajax or is it not rendered properly?

Comment: hi @Jdrupal  Thank you for your answer .. now the map is lading the Json object is sent but the Key  `"feature:[]" ` is empty. With View preview :
 `features […]
0 {…}
type point
lat 48.862725
lon 2.287592
entity_id 4675 `
The coordinate are here.

Comment: yes now with  `$view->buildRenderable('block', $args)` the map is rendered .. but there no markers on the map . after looking the Json i am seeing that is missing the key `feature`

Comment: OK, are the markers sent as contextual filters, if so, have you then remembered to add them to $args when rendering your view?

Comment: Yes 
` $args = [4679 + 4675];

    $view = Views::getView('map');

    if (is_object($view)) {
      $view->setArguments($args);
      $view->setDisplay('block');
      $view->preExecute();
      $view->execute();
      $content = $view->buildRenderable('block', $args);
    }`

Comment: Try `$args['4679+4675']` instead.